# Extract only the body part of incoming emails using bash

Tags: bash, maildir

I use `offlineimap` to fetch the mails into a Maildir folder.

I want to automatically parse all new incoming emails in a Maildir folder and send only the "from", "subject" and "body" as an instant message somewhere else.

So I try to process all mails with

```
MPATH=~/Mail 

if [ -n "$(ls "$MPATH/INBOX/new/")" ]; then 
    for f in "$MPATH/INBOX/new/"*; do  
        SUB="$(cat "$f"|grep '^Subject' | head -n1 | sed "s/Subject: //g")"                                                                                       
        FROM="$(cat "$f" | grep '^From' | head -n1 | head -n 1|sed "s/From: //g")"                                                                                
        BODY="$(cat "$f"|sed -e '1,/Content-Transfer-Encoding/d')"
        MESS="$FROM: $SUB$BODY"

        echo $f 
        echo "$MESS" 
        mv "$f" "$MPATH/INBOX/cur/" 
    done 
fi
```

This already works fine for some simple emails, but how do I get rid of everything that is not the plain body, like signatures, attachements,...?

Comment: Use a tool that understands mail instead of hacking it up with simple string processing?

Comment: I would, if there is a simple tool for the bash commandline?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? "Read" your email?

Comment: Find an MDA you can configure to run commands on email as it gets delivered?

Comment: I use `offlineimap` to fetch the mails into a Maildir folder at the moment

Comment: Check out [formail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/formail.1.html) to extract email headers

Comment: @glennjackman: How do you install formail? it is not in the debian repositories

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=formail&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any

Comment: So i have to install the whole procmail? Can't i just get the formail bin somehow?

Comment: Any luck with that? I'm looking for similar thing.

Comment: There's *so* very much wrong here. Start with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...and then why in the world would you `cat` a file over and over, instead of just reading it in one pass and parsing out the parts you want?

Comment: (...though if we needed MIME support, personally, I'd probably use Python's standard-library tooling rather than trying to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: I would be happy, of you put this in an answer with a solution to use

Answer (score 4):

As suggested on formail manpage, that worked for me:

```
cat mailfile | sed -e '1,/^$/ d'
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered in the comments, `formail` from the `procmail` package seems to do the job nicely:

```
$ sudo apt-get install procmail

$ cat test.eml | formail -x To
 test@atleticomadridhistory.com

$ cat test.eml | formail -x Subject
 hello

$ cat test.eml | formail -x Content
 multipart/alternative; boundary="f403043eea78e8658a0554677278"
```

Credits: @glennjackman